# Checkbox to String JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and i am doing a mini activity where the user can convert the value of the checkbox into a string and it will be shown into the alert box.

This is my code but whenever I click the button, it shows "undefined" on the price.

```
var riceChk;
var price;

alert(price);

riceChk = document.getElementById("rice").value;

if (riceChk.checked == true) 
{
    price="20";              
}
else
{

}
```

A little help would be very great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
riceChk = document.getElementById("rice");
```

You are getting `value` which is not valid for `checkbox` if you want to check for `checked`.

Also you have set `alert` before `setting` any `value` to `price` so it is `undefined`

Comment: hello! still the same, undefined.

Comment: you are alerting before the `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using the value before assign it.

```
var riceChk;
var price;

riceChk = document.getElementById("rice");

if (riceChk.checked == true){
    price="20";              
}else{
    price="riceChk wrong";//Just in case the flow is coming here.
}

alert(price);
```

Comment: hello! it only shows "rice wrong" even if i change the boolean to true.

Comment: hello again! i removed the .value and it worked! by the way thank you!